# How to loop a dataframe using a pipeline

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop

im trying to loop mi df using a for based in a vector whit the names of the columns what i want to loop, the code is:

```
percep <- clv_zmvm #unique key column (CVEGEO)

#the columns from E1617_zmvm
vect_var <- c("ts18","ts19", "ts20", "ts21", "ts22", "ts23", "ts24") 

for (x in vect_var){
  v <- E1617_zmvm %>% group_by(CVEGEO) %>% filter(x>=2) %>% summarise(n())
  names(v)=c("CVEGEO", x) #rename n() column in v
  percep <- percep %>% left_join(v) #join the v result
}
```

The code works, the problem is all the columns have the same values and that isnt correct.

Comment: Please don't post images of data; [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for alternatives.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'vect_var' are strings.  We can convert to `sym`bol and evaluate

```
for (x in vect_var){
  v <- E1617_zmvm %>% 
        group_by(CVEGEO) %>%
        filter(!! rlang::sym(x)>=2) %>% 
         summarise(n())
  names(v)=c("CVEGEO", x) #rename n() column in v
  percep <- percep %>% 
            left_join(v) #join the v result
 }
```

---

Or another option is `across/if_any/if_all` (it doesn't matter much as we are only doing one column at a time

```
for (x in vect_var){
  v <- E1617_zmvm %>% 
        group_by(CVEGEO) %>%
        filter(across(all_of(x), all_vars(. >=2 )) %>% 
        # or another way
        # filter(if_all(all_of(x), ~ . >= 2)) %>%
         summarise(n())
  names(v)=c("CVEGEO", x) #rename n() column in v
  percep <- percep %>% 
            left_join(v) #join the v result
 }
```

Comment: Thanks so much Akrun, the first way works perfectly.
I can´t understand yet the    !!rlang::sym()    what i should read about that?